# Use text content from cell as column variable in the same JOIN query

Tags: mysql

I have a system with translations and I want to get the amount of translated messages inside the same query as the language itself in order to create a message like "134/943 Strings translated".

Therefore I first get the language and the title stored in the `languages`-table and then `LEFT JOIN` the total amount of strings that exist.

Now in the third line of the following code is my problem: Basically I want to get the value out of the cell from **a.language** and insert it into the query for the counting of translated strings.

```sql
SELECT a.`language`, a.`title`, b.`total`, c.`translated` FROM `languages` a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as `total` FROM `translations` WHERE 1) b ON 1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as `translated` FROM `translations` WHERE `(a.`language`)` IS NOT NULL) c ON 1
```

Replacing (a.`language`) with the value out of the `languages` table.

So the third line should end up with

```sql
WHERE `en_gb` IS NOT NULL
```

for English and

```sql
WHERE `de_de` IS NOT NULL
```

for the German language in order to get the amount of strings already translated of each language.

My tables look like this:

**`languages`:**

```
| language |  title  |
|----------|---------|
|  de_de   | German  |
|  en_gb   | English |
```

**`translations`:**

```
|    key     |   de_de    |     en_gb    |
|------------|------------|--------------|
| main.hello |  Hallo!    |   Hello!     |
| main.bye   |  Tschüss!  |   Bye!       |
| main.what  |  Was?      |   *NULL*     |
```

In this specific case my query should output the following result:

```
|  language  |  title   |   total   |  translated   |
|------------|----------|-----------|---------------| 
|  de_de     | German   |    3      |     3         |
|  en_gb     | English  |    3      |     2         |
```

because there is one string that is not translated yet.

Is there even a way in doing this or do I have to create two querys: One asking for the languages and then for each language asking for how many strings have already been translated?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `key` is not a valid column name. The select is not valid as well.

Comment: `key` is not the problem in this case. I know that this SELECT is invalid... and that's the problem I have. I need to somehow get the a.\`language\` text and put it into the query of the second "LEFT JOIN" command

Comment: Is this something that dynamic sql would help with?

Answer (score 0):

@NicolaUetz I agree with @HoneyboyWilson, with your current table structures the only way you can accomplish this is by dynamic sql.

I know this isn't the answer you were looking for but instead of trying to do something abnormal to get this to work if possible I would strongly suggest changing the structure of your tables. I would change the `translations` table to have 3 columns:

> `language` | `key` | `translation`

where the language is a foreign key back to the `language` column on your `languages` table, `key` is the word to be translated and `translation` is the translation of that word into the language.

Here's the code to create the tables like this and to populate them with data:

```
CREATE TABLE `languages` (`language` TEXT, `title` TEXT);

CREATE TABLE `translations` (`language` TEXT, `key` TEXT, `translation` TEXT);

INSERT INTO `languages` (`language`, `title`)
VALUES
('de_de', 'German'),
('en_gb', 'English');

INSERT INTO `translations` (`language`, `key`, `translation`)
VALUES
('de_de', 'hello', 'Hallo!'),
('en_gb', 'hello', 'Hello!'),
('de_de', 'bye', 'Tschuss!'),
('en_gb', 'bye', 'Bye!'),
('de_de', 'what', 'Was?');
```

And here is the query you would run to get the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT `a`.`language`, 
    `a`.`title`,
    COUNT(`t`.`translation`) AS `translated`
FROM `languages` AS `a`
LEFT JOIN `translations` AS `t` ON `t`.`language` = `a`.`language`
GROUP BY `a`.`language`, `a`.`title`;
```

[Here is the example on db-fiddle;](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x4uRR1eP28Ef3cb6yHFPtD/0)

This approach is a better example of how relational database tables should be set up in relation to each other.

If it isn't possible to change your table structure then dynamic sql is the only option.

Hope this helps.